# The error of subtract between date in Python

Tags: python

I got some date from mongodb on python.
And there are two dates as below.

```
// type of values
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

// values
2020-01-27 21:07:16.755000 // pick-up
2020-01-27 20:10:00 // drop
```

When the difference of the dates is positive, it gives this. This is correc answer.

```
pick-up - drop = 0:57:16.755000
```

But When the difference of date is negative, it gives werid value.

```
drop - pick-up = -1 day, 23:02:43.245000
```

I hope to get this value.

```
drop - pick-up = -0:57:16.755000
```

How can I get this? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only date values are negative, hours -- positive. To get negative seconds use:

```py
(drop - pick-up).total_seconds()
```